# how to get search result from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am using EditTextView , where user enter some text and make a search. 
I want to search the Wikipedia for and get result against the text. How do I can search a query from Wikipedia. I found the API. But I did not found a way to get the search result for my text.

> e.g. If I enter "computer virus"

**what will be the query for this ?**

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch